# Hangman wrong guesses not printing correctly

Tags: java

I have this Hangman program that i am working on for school and i cant get the number of wrong guesses to print correctly when the user guesses a wrong letter. Here is my code that i got so far, i would appreciate any tips.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HangmanTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] wordBank = { "madelynn", "crystal", "mcbride", "daughter",
                "adorable", "beautiful", "andrew", "programming", "alyssa",
                "computers", "mcbreezy", "maddy", "happy", "vacation", "beach",
                "java", "benefical", "military", "veteran", "standale",
                "lions", "tigers", "redwings", "pistons", "michigan",
                "football", "baseball", "hockey", "basketball", "golf" };
        int minimum = 0;
        int maximum = wordBank.length - 1;
        String again;

        do {
            int choice = minimum + (int) (Math.random() * maximum);

            String word = wordBank[choice];

            // Converts the random word to asterix
            String userWord = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                userWord += "*";
            }

            // Breaks into a bunch of characters
            char[] userWordCh = userWord.toCharArray();

            // Show the random word
            System.out.println("The word for you to guess is " + userWord);

            // instantiate a scanner object
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int size = word.length();
            int rightGuesses = 0;
            int wrongGuesses = 0;

            while (size != rightGuesses) {
                System.out.println("Enter a character: ");
                String response = input.next();
                char ch = response.charAt(0);

                char[] wordChars = word.toCharArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    if (wordChars[i] == ch) {
                        userWordCh[i] = ch;
                        ++rightGuesses;
                    } else {
                        ++wrongGuesses;
                    }
                } // end of for loop

                System.out.print("The word is: ");
                for (int j = 0; j < userWordCh.length; j++)
                    System.out.print(userWordCh[j]);

                System.out.println();
            } // end of while loop

            System.out.println("You had " + wrongGuesses + " wrong guesses.");

            System.out.println("Would you like to play again y/n: ");
            again = input.next();

        } while (again.equals("y"));

    }
}
```

Comment: what makes it wrong? help point us in right direction

Comment: What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: also you have an error in your logic. I can guess the same letter over and over and get X right guesses and win

Comment: Agreed, you can easily check `userWordCh` to check for the presence of a duplicate guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in your for loop. You are iterating over each letter, and for every letter that doesn't match yours, you mark it as an incorrect guess. It should only be marked incorrect if NONE of the letters are correct. Additionally it should only be marked right if you haven't marked it already.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HangmanTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] wordBank = { "madelynn", "crystal", "mcbride", "daughter",
                "adorable", "beautiful", "andrew", "programming", "alyssa",
                "computers", "mcbreezy", "maddy", "happy", "vacation", "beach",
                "java", "benefical", "military", "veteran", "standale",
                "lions", "tigers", "redwings", "pistons", "michigan",
                "football", "baseball", "hockey", "basketball", "golf" };
        int minimum = 0;
        int maximum = wordBank.length - 1;
        String again;

        do {
            int choice = minimum + (int) (Math.random() * maximum);

            String word = wordBank[choice];

            // Converts the random word to asterix
            String userWord = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                userWord += "*";

            }

            String guessedLetters="";
            // Breaks into a bunch of characters
            char[] userWordCh = userWord.toCharArray();

            // Show the random word
            System.out.println("The word for you to guess is " + userWord);

            // instantiate a scanner object
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int size = word.length();
            int rightGuesses = 0;
            int wrongGuesses = 0;
            boolean foundLetter;
            char[] wordChars = word.toCharArray();

            guessLoop:
            while (size != rightGuesses) {
                System.out.println("Enter a character: ");
                String response = input.next();
                char ch = response.charAt(0);


                foundLetter=false;
                for (int i=0;i<guessedLetters.size();i++){
                    if (ch == guessedLetters.charAt(i)){
                         System.out.println("Already guessed that letter!");
                         continue guessLoop;
                    }
                }

                guessedLetters+=response;
                for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                    if (wordChars[i] == ch) {
                           foundLetter=true;
                           userWordCh[i] = ch;
                           ++rightGuesses;                            
                    } 
                } // end of for loop
                if(!foundLetter)
                     ++wrongGuesses;
                System.out.print("The word is: ");
                for (int j = 0; j < userWordCh.length; j++)
                    System.out.print(userWordCh[j]);

                System.out.println();
            } // end of while loop

            System.out.println("You had " + wrongGuesses + " wrong guesses.");

            System.out.println("Would you like to play again y/n: ");
            again = input.next();

        } while (again.equals("y"));

    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked but now if you have more then one of the same letter in the word like apple and you guessed the letter p it only puts one p in and then you have to guess p again to get the second p how do i make it now so it will change each letter that is the same when you guess it once

Comment: o shiz, just remove the break in my if statement

Comment: how would you make it so if they guess the same letter and it was already picked it would tell you that you already picked that one and to pick a different letter i dont really need to do this but i think it would be cool to learn how i could do it thanks

Comment: check out my changes. doing this removes the need to check for '*' in userword since you would have already guessed that letter

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (wordChars[i] == ch) {
        userWordCh[i] = ch;
        ++rightGuesses;
    } else {
        ++wrongGuesses;
    }
} // end of for loop
```

In this loop, you increment rightGuesses by 1 every time the guess matches a letter in the word, and wrongGueeses by 1 every time the guess does not match a letter in the word. As you can imagine, this will lead to the numbers, collectively, being incremented by the same number as the number of letters, when it should only be incremented once.

Try something like:

```
boolean foundMatch = false;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (wordChars[i] == ch) {
        userWordCh[i] = ch;
        if (!foundMatch)
        {
            ++rightGuesses;
            foundMatch = true;
        }
    }
}
if (!foundMatch)
{
    ++wrongGuesses;
}
// end of for loop
```

Now we only increment one of rightGuesses and wrongGuesses once - rightGuesses can only be incremented if we have not found a match (setting found match to true), and wrongGuesses can only be incremented once if we have not found a match.

Comment: this has the same problem, incorrect right guesses to win the game. for the work "dog" I can guess "d" three times to win it

Comment: In which case, add another check to the if to ensure `userWordCh[i] != '*'`.

Comment: @75inchpianist Well, you didn't say that was a problem when you posted the question ;)

Comment: @Patashu i didnt post the question. This implementation won't work. i edited my response and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but I think this might be wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
     if (wordChars[i] == ch) {
         userWordCh[i] = ch;
         ++rightGuesses;
     } else {
         ++wrongGuesses;
     }
} // end of for loop
```

This will increment the `rightGuesses` and `wrongGuesses` variables for each character in the word that matches/doesn't match the inputted character. Instead, you need to set a flag when a character "matches", then check that flag at the end to update `rightGuesses` and `wrongGuesses`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (wordChars[i] == ch) {
                    userWordCh[i] = ch;
                    ++rightGuesses;
                } else {
                    ++wrongGuesses;
                }
            } // end of for loop
```

This for loop is causing your problem with wrong guesses, since it will say that a character is a wrong guess even though it is in the word.  An option you can do is have some boolean that is switched to true when it finds the letter.  That way, when you leave the for loop, you check to see if that value is true. If it isn't, increment the wrong guesses.